# Rails before_filter with parameter from methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, before-filter

I have a series of methods, with similar structure and sharing a common parameter:

- def deposit (amount)
- def transfer (amount, to)
- def refund (amount)

I would like to check if the balance is greater than amount before calling these actions. Otherwise, I have to repeat check_balance in every method

Is there a way I can user before_filter to call check_balance(amount) with amount passed from the methods I want to apply to?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're not really looking for some `before_filter` since you want to pass arguments (unless arguments are taken directly from `params` but then the syntax would be wrong).

You should create a new method in you controller

```
private
def check_balance amount
  # whatever you need
end
```

An call this as you need in your action

```
def index
  #some code
  check_balance(current_amount)
  #other code
end
```

But you're sure this kind of code isn't related directly to the model? If so, it should be refactored inside the model itself.

Comment: Sorry about confusing between parameters and method arguments. You understood my question correctly though. I know I can call check_balance on every method. I just wonder if there is a way I can avoid to repeat the same call so many times.

Comment: because the call isn't made just before or just after an action, there is no really way to avoid the repetition. Whatever, code is very readable and testable so I can't see any architecture default.

Comment: That's the answer I am looking for. Thank you.

Comment: I agree that this probably doesn't belong in the actions themselves; if this related to our previous discussion, it should live wherever the transfer is created.